# Method Overloading in Excel COM Interop

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com, overloading

I am having a lot of troubles with method overloading here and have no idea why only one method gets called each time regardless the number of parameters I pass into. Below is the sample code.

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual), ComVisible(true)]
public class myClass
{
    //constructor
    public myClass() {}

    //base method
    public string myfunction(string id, string pk) {return results;}

    //overloading method 1
    public string myfunction(string id, string pk, string param1) { return results;}

    //overloading method 2
    public string myfunction(string id, string pk, string param1, string param2) {return results;}



    [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]
        public static void RegisterFunction(Type type)
        {

            Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(
              GetSubKeyName(type, "Programmable"));
            RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(
              GetSubKeyName(type, "InprocServer32"), true);
            key.SetValue("",
              System.Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\mscoree.dll",
              RegistryValueKind.String);
        }
        [ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute]
        public static void UnregisterFunction(Type type)
        {

            Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey(
              GetSubKeyName(type, "Programmable"), false);
        }
        private static string GetSubKeyName(Type type,
          string subKeyName)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder s =
              new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            s.Append(@"CLSID\{");
            s.Append(type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper());
            s.Append(@"}\");
            s.Append(subKeyName);
            return s.ToString();
        }

}
```

So when I tested it in Excel, the base method worked fine and I could get the expected value. However, it would fail if I tried the rest two functions using method overloading. They simply didn't get called for some reason. Am I missing something in the code? Can anyone help me please?  Thanks very much.

Edit:

Through some experiments, it occurs to me that there only 1 method can be recognized, which normally is the first method. So if I swap the order between base method and overloading method 1, the overloading method 1 will be called instead of the base method. Looks like the whole class just gets stuck in the first method and wouldn't go on.

Comment: I do it in the excel by using this `=myfunction(1,20)`

Comment: or for adding optional parameters, just do `=myfunction(1,20,myparamvalue)`

Comment: Even if you call myfun(1,1,1) the same happens?

Comment: yes. In excel, you only see #value! appearing in the cell.

Comment: I think it's definitely not using the correct function.

Comment: Ok may not be the best solution even you call other function than an overloading function with 3 params? Same happens? Just a lil test!!

Comment: Same error! Get no results back except #VALUE! :( I put a break point in the code where my overloading function sits, and it's just not getting into there. :(

Comment: As i said forget calling ovarloading method as of now. Just use a diff method say FunX for now and test. See if it gets hit.

Comment: well of course if you use FunX then you get #NAME? error

Comment: So the new method isnt also gettng hit?

Comment: no, it's not. As I mentioned in the EDIT, I found that only the first function would be called and the rest ignored somehow.

Comment: @woodykiddy let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2598/discussion-between-zenwalker-and-woodykiddy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Excelfriend, you **can't polymorphize** a a worksheet function. A
> worksheet function called, say, `GETSALESFORWEEK` can only have one
> entry point. If you provide two, say `GETSALESFORWEEK(int WeekNumber)`
> and `GETSALESFORWEEK(string WeekName)` then Excel 2007 will expose these
> functions as `GETSALESFORWEEK` and `GETSALESFORWEEK_2`.

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gabhan_berry/archive/2008/04/07/writing-custom-excel-worksheet-functions-in-c_2d00_sharp.aspx

Well I guess that answers my questions. Sadly, no method overloading for custom Excel functions :(

Solution:

```cs
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual), ComVisible(true)]
public class myClass
{
    //constructor
    public myClass() {}

    //base method
    /**public string myfunction(string id, string pk) {return results;}**/

    //overloading method 1
    /**public string myfunction(string id, string pk, string param1) { return results;}**/

    //just use 1 method, but make the last two arguments optional by setting default values
    public string myfunction(string id, string pk, string param1 = "", string param2 = "") {return results;}

    [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]
    public static void RegisterFunction(Type type)
    {
        Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(
          GetSubKeyName(type, "Programmable"));
        RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(
          GetSubKeyName(type, "InprocServer32"), true);
        key.SetValue("",
          System.Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\mscoree.dll",
          RegistryValueKind.String);
    }

    [ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute]
    public static void UnregisterFunction(Type type)
    {
        Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey(
          GetSubKeyName(type, "Programmable"), false);
    }

    private static string GetSubKeyName(Type type, string subKeyName)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        s.Append(@"CLSID\{");
        s.Append(type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper());
        s.Append(@"}\");
        s.Append(subKeyName);
        return s.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

COM Interop does not support overloading: see the "Overloading" section in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms993883.aspx).

The Type Library Exporter will rename overloaded members by appending a prefix (e.g. _2).