# Excel VBA extension DLL "Wrong number of agruments or invalid property assignment"

Tags: c#, excel, vba, dll

I wrote an extension dll in C# which I'm calling in the VBA code.
Since the code in the DLL is somewhat more complex I decided to split the functionality into some classes.
This means that the Main entrypoint to my DLL is still the Main method but in there I can call the different other classes and methods.

All of this worked fine until today.
I changed the signature of one method a bit because I need one more variable coming from Excel VBA and suddenly I could not call the method anymore and its throwing me the following exception:

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

The code in VBA from which I call the DLL is as follows (the variable `orig_value` is the one I added)

```vb
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)       
    If TlbMain Is Nothing Then
        Set TlbMain = New EstimationTypeLibrary.Main
    End If

    Call TlbMain.EstimationSheetChanged(ActiveWorkbook, Target, orig_value)
End Sub
```

The code in the C# DLL which I call from VBA is as follows (the variable `originalValue` is the one I added)

```cs
public void EstimationSheetChanged(Workbook activeWorkbook, Range range, string originalValue)
{
    PublicEstimationSheetProperties.OriginalValue = originalValue;
    EstimationOnChange.EstimationSheetChanged(activeWorkbook, range);
}
```

Comment: Have you actually re-registered the C# assembly?

Comment: Yes I even deleted teh entry in the registry which was then recreated when I built the assembly again.

Comment: Verify that the registry points to the actual location of the assembly, and that the assembly at that location is the updated one. Use [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to be sure. Obviously Excel will need to be restarted, and be closed when you re-register.

Comment: Ok I unregistered the assembly and registered it again while using Procmon which also showed the activity. Also Excel was closed but there is still no diffrence in behavior.

Comment: Can you tell me if VBA is at all capable of handling overloaded Methods because thats what i am doing currently in my c# assembly with that Method

Comment: No, VBA is [not able](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7102184/11683) to use overloaded methods.

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem. There is still a exception coming up when I delete the old Method saying "Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface" but I get get around that by just leaving it there and just calling the new one.